# Read event log in C#

Tags: c#, events, logging

I'm trying to read event logs for my application **EventLoggingApp**. The problem is reading logs for my single source (EventLoggingApp).

This code read logs for every source. What is the problem? Any advice?

```
static void ReadEvenLog()
{
    string eventLogName = "Application";
    string sourceName = "EventLoggingApp";
    string machineName = "Tom";

    EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
    eventLog.Log = eventLogName;
    eventLog.Source = sourceName;
    eventLog.MachineName = machineName;

    foreach (EventLogEntry log in eventLog.Entries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\n",log.Source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 33):

Try this:

```
EventLog log = new EventLog("Security");
var entries = log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
                         .Where(x => x.InstanceId == 4624)
                         .Select(x => new
                         {
                             x.MachineName,
                             x.Site,
                             x.Source,
                             x.Message
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: An explanation as to what's achieved by this code snippet would be nice...

Comment: @Domenico can you explain how do you get the InstanceId? Would be very helpfull? Thx!

Comment: @Darem i found this in Evend ID column of Security Windows Registry

Comment: Error: System.Security.SecurityException: 'Requested registry access is not allowed.'

Comment: @anhtv13 may the user you're using is not allowed to read the registry

Comment: This code must be run as admin.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries.aspx) on MSDN. You can't read event log entries by source. Only log name matters. Instead you can create separate event log for you application or filter entries by verifying Source property of each entry in foreach loop.

Comment: Thx, I am from Slovakia, your eng is much more better than my :)

Answer (score 1):

MSDN [(1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)[(2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.source%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) says that Source is for writing event logs only.

> It is not necessary to specify a Source  when only reading from a log. You can specify only the Log  name and MachineName  (server computer name) properties for the EventLog  instance. In either case, the Entries member is automatically populated with the event log's list of entries. You can select the appropriate index for an item in this list to read individual entries. (1)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you were trying to print on the console. If it is the **message** in each event log entry that you are trying to print, inside the `foreach` loop you should have this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine(log.Message + "\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you connect to localhost set MachineName to "." 
Check if user has right to read from eventlog

Comment: Since he gets ALL logs from his machine, there are no security problems.